# When rendering textured objects are stacked on top of each other?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

In my scene, I'm trying to display textured objects falling next to each other (coins all sharing the same texture)

When I rendered my scene with the textured objects however, they stacked on top of each other and ignored their programmed positioning.

After the scene has ended, and I go back to edit mode, the coins show they are stacked on top of each other even in there, almost as if at render time the entire scene is changed to make them stack on top of each other.

New to Blender, could not find a similar question.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Could you add some images to make your question clearer?

Comment: The first thing I'd check is to akesure scale, rotation,  and location transforms were applied.